# Importing a 3d model and displaying it in a swing component

Tags: java, swing, 3d-model

**I want to import a 3d model** (preferably a wavefront obj file) and then **be able to display that model in a swing component**. From there I want to be able to move (translate) the model based on live input data.

Any suggestions on how this could be done?

Comment: You could write your own wrapper for OpenGL, then write a .obj importer and render it out all on your own, but then again that's already been done for you in a convenient library, so why not use it?

Comment: @Quirliom I haven't used OpenGL before so I'm not comfortable using the JOGL library. I've tried running example code linked in this thread: http://forum.jogamp.org/Loading-and-drawing-obj-models-td2708428.html but wasn't able to get it working.

Comment: Then *what* makes you think that it will be any easier *without* a dedicated library?

Comment: @Quirliom I didn't mean that I don't want to use a dedicated library, just that I wasn't comfortable with using OpenGL yet, as in I don't have experience with it, so I don't know how to use it to load obj files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to load a local obj file with the j3d library using a slightly modified version of the code found here:

https://java.net/projects/j3d-examples/sources/svn/content/branches/dev-1_4/src/ObjLoad/ObjLoad.java?rev=192

Comment: java.net is closed. The link is dead.